# Animation that uses white noise

Tags: text, effects, video

I have requirement for an intro to youtube channel (comedy), and idea is to make fun of [HBO intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLvYD7Vd31A) in a way that out of white noise instead of 'HBO' youtube comedy channel name would appear. How do you think HBO did this effect with white noise? What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: @DA01 could you post it as an answer please. Thanks.

Comment: There are YouTube videos which may be helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0I4mTEdAf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely recorded actual static--which is hard to do these days since it's a remnant of our analog broadcasting days. But it's trivial to make noise in a tool like PhotoShop. Just make a bunch of noise frames and string them together in an animation